# Can someone identify the font in this photo?

Tags: fonts

This is the logo from my grandfather's old restaurant. I'm trying to reproduce this old t-shirt for his birthday. Does anyone recognize this font? It looks like there might be more than one used here.

[image]

Comment: In all honesty, with the random kerning and inconsistent serifs, I somewhat wonder if it's a "font" at all and not merely hand drawn type - At least for the "Lunch Break" aspect. The rest is a font - but I can't recall the name.

Comment: Hrm. It's pretty old, so I suppose it could be hand drawn. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the "Lunch break" is hand drawn. My guess would be that it is an old typesetting font, or custom cut stamp. Probably not available as digital font. Running it through fontsquirrel.com/matcherator I found two that are relatively similar.

[image: Classic Round Medium + Extra Exta Regular]

For the smaller font a Garamond or Baskerville are close.

Answer (score 1):

The big font is hard to identify, which is annoying as it has a ton of distinctive letter shapes despite the limited character set. Identifont didn't find anything quite right. If you need the exact font the big player in display type in this period was ITC, you might find it searching through their library. My closest suggestion then would be [ITC Jeepers](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/jeepers-itc/), or [Maiandra by Dennis Pasternak](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/galapagos/maiandra/) or [Fritz by Christian Schwartz](https://store.typenetwork.com/foundry/fontbureau/fonts/fritz), which get the right slightly-wonky, monoline letter structure despite only having minimal serifs. Or [ITC Souvenir](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/souvenir/?lastItem=8&tab=individualStyles), which has some similar letter shapes but more contrast.

The small text is in a thick-and-thin "stressed" sans-serif style. [Acme Gothic](https://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/acme-gothic) is not the font in this image but it's a very good digital version of this style.